# Find the distance between points with python objects and classes

Tags: python, class, object, oop, instance

I'm just getting into OOP in Python and struggling with classes. Basically I'm creating a method that needs to find the Euclidean distance between two points. I've created a method that creates the two points, it works. I've then created a method `__sub__` that subtracts from those two points with another point instance, it then squares those two points respectively. That also works.

Now I need to create a method `point_distance` that takes in the result from `__sub__` and sums both those points together, and then performs a square root on the sum. I have included some pseuodocode at the bottom. I've tried a few things but I think I'm not fully understanding the fundamentals of OOP. Any help appreciated

```
class Point(object):
    """A 2D point in the cartesian plane"""
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        """
        Creates a point at the two co-ordinates

        Parameters:
            x (float): x coordinate in the 2D cartesian plane
            y (float): y coordinate in the 2D cartesian plane
        """

        self._x = x
        self._y = y


    def __sub__(self, other):
        """Return a new Point after subtracting this from 'other'
        Perform vector subtraction of the points, and then squares each of them respectively  
        point1 - point2 -> Point3 - Point4
        Parameters:
        other (Point): other point to be subtracted from this point.
        Return:
        Point: New point at position 'self' - 'other', then both squared
        """
        
        return Point((self._x - other.x())**2, (self._y - other.y())**2) 

    def x(self):
        """(float) Return the x coordinate of the point"""
        return self._x

    def y(self):
        """(float) Return the y coordinate of the point"""
        return self._y
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Point({}, {})'.format(self._x, self._y)
   
    ##Problem in pseudocode below
  
    def point_distance(self, result from __sub__):
        add the two points together
        return the sqaure root of the sum of the two points obtained above
```

Comment: `point_distance()` should take `(self, other)` as parameters just like `__sub__()` does otherwise you're making it overly complicated.

Comment: And your `__sub__` function should just do subtraction.  There is no reason for it to do squaring.   Then `point_distance(self, other)` would  find the value of `temp = self - other`, and return `math.sqrt(temp.x ** 2 + temp.y ** 2)`

Comment: @Frank Yellin thanks for all your help! Solved. I was way overthinking this

Comment: @Pavel You're right, code was much simpler than my initial approach. Thanks

Comment: For reference, full code that worked `temp = Point(self._x - other.x(), self._y - other.y())`
and then returning `return math.sqrt(temp.x()**2 + temp.y()**2)`